# google drive SDK swift authorization

Tags: swift, google-drive-api, authorization, swift2

I am using Google Drive SDK in my Swift 2.0 project and I successfully authorize in my `ViewController.swift` (the first view I loaded).
I also created an online Google Doc.

However, When I am in Other ViewController (`PropertyTableViewController.swift`)
I want to upload data to my existing Google Doc which was in PropertyTableViewController. It just wouldn't work

I try to call upload function in ViewController.swift, however my authorization status just misses after I enter another swift file.

So, how can I save my authorization status (I successfully generate access token and refresh token) and use it whenever I want?